# I enter numbers and then the content of an array will show

Tags: javascript, arrays

How will I get this work please? I enter number and then the content of an array will show. Please see my code

```js
var colorArray = ["Crimson", "Olive", "Red", "Yellow", "Black", "Beige", "Pink", "Orange"] = document.getElementById("enterNumber").value;

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  colorArray = document.getElementById("enterNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("colorMagic").innerHTML = colorArray[enterNumber];

}
```

```html
<p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:17px;">Please enter a <span style="color:red;">number</span>.</p>
<input id="enterNumber" class="textbox" type="text" value="" />

<button id="btn">Enter!</button>

<p id=""><span id="colorMagic">Crimson</span> is my new favorite color!</p>
```

Comment: i dont think thats what he wants, he just wants to change text in the span id colorMagic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some errors in your code :

1. At the end of array initialization, you are trying to assign input value. I don't know why you are trying to do that anyway, it's a wrong syntax.
2. Within the click event handler, you are updating the array variable with the input value. So no longer access to the array within the callback so it always produces `undefined`.

It's always better to cache the element object instead of getting from DOM each time.

```html
<input id="enterNumber" class="textbox" type="text" value="" />

<button id="btn">Enter!</button>

<p id=""><span id="colorMagic">Crimson</span> is my new favorite color!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var colorArray = ["Crimson", "Olive", "Red", "Yellow", "Black", "Beige", "Pink", "Orange"];

  // cache elements object into varibales
  var colorMagic = document.getElementById("colorMagic");
  var numberInput = document.getElementById("enterNumber");

  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
    // get value from input
    var val = numberInput.value;
    // use || to handle if index is undefined
    colorMagic.innerHTML = colorArray[val] || '(Not a valid index)';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Pranav C Balan just what I needed. I'm so sorry I'm a newbie in javascript and I'm learning, the comments you added is helpful I can understand the code. Thank you.

Comment: @L.j :  glad to help :)